# Clusterparameter ObjectGUID shifted

Tags: powershell, failovercluster

So I try to link the networkname of a cluster resource to the AD object by the objectGUID in powershell.

If I execute following command `Get-ClusterResource -Cluster CLxxx -Name NameOfResource` the NetworkName object is returned.

I can ask for the clusterparameters and the parameter ObjectGUID `(Get-ClusterResource -Cluster CLxxx -Name NameOfResource | Get-ClusterParameter -Name objectguid).Value`

It will return something like `5efa2b5674c75d43bcdad1c2c183d5ca`

So far so good.

If I try to get the ADobject from Active Directory `(Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -Like "$Name"}).ObjectGUID.guid`

It will return something like `562bfa5e-c774-435d-bcda-d1c2c183d5ca`

It is almost the same but not quite.
Al the characters are there but not in the correct order.

ClusterParameter: 5efa2b5674c75d43bcdad1c2c183d5ca

Active Directory:     562bfa5e-c774-435d-bcda-d1c2c183d5ca

If you look at the string AD returned you can split the string in 5 sequences on the `-`.
The last 2 are in the correct order but the first three have to switch front to back (2 characters at a time).

ClusterParameter: 5efa2b56-74c7-5d43-bcda-d1c2c183d5ca

Active Directory:     562bfa5e-c774-435d-bcda-d1c2c183d5ca

It is the same on 2008,2012 and 2016.

Does someone have an explanation for this?